# DateTime ToFileTime and ToFileTimeUtc have same output

Tags: c#, datetime

I opened a file and used `ToUniversalTime()` and `ToLocalTime()` and output different times.  However, when I use `ToFileTime()` and `ToFileTimeUtc()`, I get the same number.  Why is this?

```
DateTime creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(@"c:\windows\setupact.log");
Console.WriteLine("utc time: " + creationTime.ToUniversalTime());
Console.WriteLine("file time: " + creationTime.ToLocalTime());
Console.WriteLine("file: " + creationTime.ToFileTime());
Console.WriteLine("utc: " + creationTime.ToFileTimeUtc());
```

output

> utc time: 8/22/2013 2:46:17 PM
>
> file time: 8/22/2013 7:46:17 AM
>
> file: 130216563774628355
>
> utc: 130216563774628355

Shouldn't file and utc be different?

Comment: [This question](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/tofiletime-vs-tofiletimeutc-issues.2642152/) and the link document offer more detail

Comment: @DStanley, I don't know if the documentation for the link it up to date.  The link to GotDotNet is broken and a google search did not turn up a web page for GotDotNet.  Also, I tested the numbers I got against LocalFileTimeToFileTime() in c++.  This takes local time and  converts it to UTC.  The output for .ToFileTimeUtc is the same as the local time in c++ and not the UTC time

Comment: What's your own timezone?

Comment: West coast USA, North America

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's good information in the existing answers, but let me attempt a pragmatic summary:

**The only time the distinction between `System.DateTime.ToFileTime()` and `System.DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc()` matters is when the instance's `.Kind` property equals `Unspecified`**, i.e., if **it's unclear whether the time value represents a *local* or *UTC* time**.
<sup>This information was actually in an answer by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) that he himself deleted.</sup>

In other word: for `System.DateTime` instances whose **`.Kind` property equals either `Local` or `Utc`** (the only other possible values), **`System.DateTime.ToFileTime()` and `System.DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc()` behave *identically*** - this is what the OP experienced, because his input value was of `.Kind` `Local` (the kind returned by `File.GetCreationTime()`).

Note that the related `System.DateTimeOffset` type by design always carries explicit UTC offset information, so there's never ambiguity, which is probably why that type has *only* a `.ToFileTime()` method (and not also `.ToFileTimeUtc()`).

As others have noted, **the *return* value *always* represents a UTC time**:

- **File time values *by definition, invariably* represent a point in time *in UTC*.**
- Thus, both `.ToFileTime()` and `.ToFileTimeUtc()` create a point in time expressed as the count of 100ns intervals since midnight January 1, 1601 UTC.

To complement the OP's own example with one where `.ToFileTime()` and `.ToFileTimeUtc()` *do* differ in outcome:

```
// Create a DateTime instance with .Kind equal to Unspecified;
// use the earliest date that can be represented as a file time.
DateTime dtUnspecified = DateTime.Parse("1601-01-01");

Console.WriteLine(
    dtUnspecified.ToFileTime() + "\n" +
    dtUnspecified.ToFileTimeUtc()
);
```

Sample output in the US Eastern time zone:

```
180000000000  // 1601-01-01T05:00:00Z - 5 AM UTC
0             // 1601-01-01T00:00:00Z - midnight UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight,
>   January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Windows
>   uses a file time to record when an application creates, accesses, or
>   writes to a file.

The number of nanoseconds since 1-1-1601 UTC, don't change no matter in which timezone you are.

From the source of the .net framwork:

```
public long ToFileTime() {
    // Treats the input as local if it is not specified
    return ToUniversalTime().ToFileTimeUtc();
}

public long ToFileTimeUtc() {
    // Treats the input as universal if it is not specified
    long ticks = ((InternalKind & LocalMask) != 0) ? ToUniversalTime().InternalTicks : this.InternalTicks;
    ticks -= FileTimeOffset;
    if (ticks < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(null, Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_FileTimeInvalid"));
    }
    return ticks;
}
```

So when you use `ToFileTimeUtc` and you have an unspecified `DateTime` it gives you the nanosecs since 1-1-1601, no matter what timezone it's originally from. Which could for an hour each year if the timezone has DST give you an invalid time.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [`ToFileTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it says:

> A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Windows uses a file time to record when an application creates, accesses, or writes to a file.

All file times are stored in UTC. Then applications such as Explorer convert the UTC time to Local Time for display purposes.

If you look further into the remarks section of [`ToFileTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will see a "Notes to Callers" section. That further explains how [`ToFileTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ToFileTimeUtc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc(v=vs.110).aspx) were expected to be used.